# Do I need any visas to layover in Oman and Qatar as an Indian Citizen?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, doha, muscat, oman-air

I am Travelling from India to Dallas using a single ticket. I have an F1 Visa and I will be using Oman Airways/Qatar.

My Itinerary is:
HYD, India to MCT, Oman (Oman Air 232)
MCT, Oman to DOHA, Qatar (Oman Air 667)
DOHA, Qatar to Dallas, US (Oman Air 6461 - operated by Qatar)

Will there be any visa issues while transferring from Oman to Qatar?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are an Indian citizen, as long as there isn't something I'm missing, should be no.

For example, you will normally need a visa if you need to clear immigration for any reason.